# loading .yml file with another path

Tags: plugins, load, yaml, message, minecraft

Actually, I'm need some help.
I started coding a minecraft plugin, even though I'm beginner with java. 
I want to load the content of a .yml file which has another path as the default files. As far as I know, i need to use `.getString(String)` for this. But I have no idea how to set another path AND use getString at once.

the method to load the Language

```
public void loadLanguage() throws IOException {
    String language = this.getConfig().getString("language");
    InputStream lang = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("languages/" + language + ".yml");
    YamlConfiguration langfile = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(lang);
    langfile.options().copyDefaults(true);
    langfile.save("plugins/Costumized/languages/" + language + ".yml");
}
```

in the main part, i need to get the specified message with getString for the message should get sended to the player runned the command.

I hope you can understand what's my problem. 
And yes, my english is horrible. sry for that.

Comment: Did you check the documentation for whatever plugin framework you are using?

Comment: yes i did. But that wasn't rly helpfull

Comment: What plugin framework are you using, e.g. Bukkit, Forge?

Comment: Look here, i think this can help:
[LINK][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136460/create-custom-bukkit-plugin-yaml-file

LG 2000YG

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SpigotLib plugin for easy configuration management:

https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/spigotlib.5925/

In order to handle several configs with it, you should make new classes for each config with static fields for simplicity.
You can save and load your configurations onEnable as follows:

```
  ConfigFile kf1,kf2;

  public void onEnable()
  {
    SU.saveResources(this, "config.yml", "config2.yml");
    kf1=new ConfigFile(new File(getDataFolder()+File.separator+"config1.yml");
    kf2=new ConfigFile(new File(getDataFolder()+File.separator+"config2.yml");
    kf1.data.deserialize(Config1.class);
    kf2.data.deserialize(Config2.class);
    SU.pm.registerEvents(this, this);
  }
```

The config saving is also very simple:

```
  public void onDisable()
  {
    kf1.save();
    kf2.save();
  }
```

So you will no longer need to use config settings like get or set, you can have any kind of data structure, which is automatically handled by the SpigotLib. So if you just need to store some strings, you can add a hashmap field to your configuration class.